# bytes are swapped when pointer cast is done in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I have an array of "unsigned short" i.e. 16-bits each element in C. I have two "unsigned short" values which should be written back in array in little endian order which means that least significant element will come first. For example, if I have following value:

```
unsigned int val = 0x12345678;
```

it should be stored in my array as:

```
unsigned short buff[10];
buff[0] = 0x5678;
buff[1] = 0x1234;
```

I have written a code to write the value at once and not extracting upper and lower 16-bits of the int value and write them separately since there might be atomicity problems. My code looks like this:

```
typedef unsigned int UINT32;
*((UINT32*)(buff)) = (value & 0xffff0000)  + (value & 0xffff);
```

Surprisingly, the code above works correctly and the results will be:

```
buff[0] is 0x5678;
buff[1] is 0x1234;
```

The problem is, as it is shown, I am saving the "unsigned short" values in big endian order and not little endian as I wish. In other words, when I cast the pointer from "unsigned short*" to "unsigned int*" the 16-bit elements are swapped automatically! Does anybody knows what happens here and why the data gets swapped?

Comment: The snarky answer is that type punning like that is undefined behaviour.

Comment: If you're writing them in LE the bytes of each *short* should also be turned. Or is the endianness you refer to only conceptual and not *actual*? If actual, the byte order of `0x12345678` should be `0x78 0x56 0x34 0x12`.

Comment: BTW: `(value & 0xffff0000)  + (value & 0xffff)` is the same thing as just `value` if `value` is 32-bits.

Comment: That is true that (value & 0xffff0000) + (value & 0xffff) is same as value itself. I just separated them manually for testing purposes. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your platform represents data in little endian format, and by casting buff to (UINT32 *), you are telling the compiler that buff must now be interpreted as pointer to unsigned int. The instruction

```
*((UINT32*)(buff)) = (value & 0xffff0000)  + (value & 0xffff);
```

Just says "write (value & 0xffff0000)  + (value & 0xffff) into this unsigned int (buff)". And that's what he does, how he stores it is not your business. You're not supposed to access either of the lower or upper 16 bits, because it is platform dependent which one comes first.

All you know is that if you access buff as an unsigned int, you will get the same value that you previously stored in there, but it is not safe to assume any particular byte order.

So basically your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: That is a good answer. The bytes are swapped according to the hardware type that is probably little endian here, as well. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, from the example you posted, it looks like little endian. Intel x86 and x86-64 series of processors use the little-endian format.